# Is there a way to close a specific tab on a browser?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, browser, popen

I am fairly new to Python and I am trying to close a specific tab from a browser. I have tried to close the process using the PID but my code does not seem to find the process. I am getting a FileNotFoundError When I look up on the task manager, there is no process with the PID that is in the "print".  Am I missing something?

```
import time
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe http://www.youtube.com")
time.sleep(10)
print(p.pid)
subprocess.Popen(['taskkill/F/T/PID', str(p.pid)])
```

I am using Python3.7 on Win10.

Comment: This entirely depends on the browser you are using. Some browsers indeed use one process per tab, others do not. And very likely the browser will become upset if you kill one of its processes; you aren't supposed to do that. If there is a supported way of closing a tab, it will depend on the browser. (Also, if you start a browser and give it a URL on the command line, it is unlikely that *that* new process will handle the new tab, wherever it ends up. Again, it depends on the browser.)

Comment: Furthermore, you need spaces in the command: `taskkill /F /T /PID 123456` (including the one preceding the number).